# Is there a way to refresh Laravel Passport's cookie tokens with a Vue.JS SPA?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-passport

For a SPA dashboard I use Laravel Passport to provide API tokens trough the [`CreateFreshApiToken`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript) web middleware. It works fine although when the user is working on stuff in the dashboard he will not have access to retrieve/post data after the token has expired, which aswell is behaviour as expected. Is there a way to refresh the cookie token trough the API? Like for example: Everytime the user is active, aka posts or retrieves something from the api, the cookie token will be refreshed so it will only expire when the user is inactive.

Answer (score 0):

If your application issues short-lived access tokens, users will need to refresh their access tokens via the refresh token that was provided to them when the access token was issued.

**Laravel**

```
 $http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;
 $response = $http->post('http://your-app.com/oauth/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
        'refresh_token' => 'the-refresh-token',
        'client_id' => 'client-id',
        'client_secret' => 'client-secret',
        'scope' => '',
    ],
]);

return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
```

**VUEJS**

```
created() {
   this.$cookie.set("token", keyValue, "expiring time")
}
```

Comment: Does refresh token requesting work for cookie based tokens set by the `CreateFreshApiToken` web middleware?

Comment: A refresh token is not generated when using the `CreateFreshApiToken` middleware.
This answer would've been correct if we were talking about authentication using the OAuth 2.0 password grant provided by Laravel Passport.

Answer (score 0):

There is [a route registered](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/758e143052f0a353df8dff9349f84601579e457d/src/RouteRegistrar.php#L99) by Passport's `RouteRegistrar` class with this purpose. As far as I can tell it is strangely left undocumented in the official documentation for Laravel Passport.

You can perform a `POST` request to the `oauth/token/refresh` endpoint, and receive a new access token at any time.
This request requires no payload, the only requirement is that you are logged in, using a traditional session in Laravel.

Note that because this route uses the `web` middleware group, your session will also automatically be prolonged upon requesting a new access token.